# The condition has length greater than 1 in function evaluation

Tags: r

I have this two functions:

```
Hwave<-function(t){
  if((0<=t & t<=1/2)){
    resultado<-t
  }else if((1/2<t & t<=1)){
    resultado<-1-t
  }else {resultado<-0}
  
  print(resultado)
}
```

And Im trying to create a new table of data by evaluating some data I have in the following way:

```
v<-c()
for(i in 0:(length(data)-1)){append(v,Hwave(data[i]),i)}
```

Then the condition has length greater than 1 error appears, but data[i] is a vector of length 1 for every entry so I don't know what is going wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

The test data im using is `data<-seq(from=0,to=1,by=2^(-8))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `i` in the `for` loop fall within the range `1` to `length(data)`, e.g.,

```
v <- c()
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  append(v, Hwave(data[i]), i)
}
```

since `data[0]` will give a syntax error.

---

Here is another workaround with vectorized version of `Hwave`, named as `Hwave_1`

```
Hwave_1 <- function(t) {
  ifelse(0 <= t & t <= 1 / 2, t, ifelse(1 / 2 < t & t <= 1, 1 - t, 0))
}
```

and you can try running `Hwave_1` over `data` without any loops

```
Hwave_1(data)
```